# How to use Laravel 9 Faker to select from a predefined array of UUIDs?

Tags: laravel, faker

How can I use Laravel Faker to select from a predefined array of UUIDs?

```
class BookShelfFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = BookShelf::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $uuids = array(
            '9f86affa-66fc-11ed-9022-0242ac120002',
            'e69e6546-d0a2-49e1-b4fe-2fe31de20252',
            'c48c6318-dbd1-4881-ab77-ffee4e1fa3b1',
            'f3031799-6cae-4edf-87a1-330f3e5d2a65',
            'e8d7f5cc-71f5-4e05-848a-1cdab53c15de'
        );
    
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->text(50),
            //'uuid' => $this->faker->uuid,
            'uuid'=> $this->faker->sequence($uuids),
            'author_id' => \App\Models\BookAuthor::factory(),
            'created_by' => \App\Models\User::factory(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Above code results in error:   `Unknown format "sequence`

Comment: you don't need faker for that. Just pick randomly from your uuids array.

Comment: I don't want random UUIDs, need these specific ones! Also, I need faker to fill in all the other fields with fake data...

Comment: then you somehow need to save the index.
'uuid' => uuids[$index]. You don't need faker for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Faker's `randomElement()`:

```
return [
    'uuid' => $this->faker->randomElement($uuids),
];
```

It will return a random element from the given array of uuids.